# Should I contact the hiring manager before background check shows a 4 month position I didn’t include on application?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, human-resources, applications, employment-gaps

Due to COVID I was employed for only 4 months and have been laid off for 11 months. Accepted an offer today contingent on background check. This 4 month gig was not listed on my resume nor the application. It will show up on the background check. Should I explain to the hiring manager now or wait for the background check. The job is not relevant to this new position nor is it listed on social media (LinkedIn or FB)

Comment: What kind of background check is this? In what industry? In which country/state? Was the 4 months position a contract job or full time employment?

Comment: New hire background check in Texas. It was a full time position that was eliminated due to the Oil and Gas downturn at the beginning of Covid. I was an Admin Assistant worked in the office for 2 weeks before they sent us home for COVID. They laid me off one month after the office opened up.

Comment: Why did you not put it on your resume?

Comment: Took it off after updating my resume. It was only a 4 month placement and it’s been over a year ago .

Comment: Most background checks will usually verify that you actually worked at the companies you claim in your CV. They likely won't look for companies you worked for that you didn't list (in Europe they would have no legal way to even get to know which companies you worked for without you providing that info).

Comment: Don't invent problems. If they ask about it, respond with truth. It is unlikely they will ask about it, and you've done nothing dishonest nor anything that tons of people haven't done while tailoring a resume to a position. Highly unlikely it'll even come up.

Answer (score 1):

1, Well 4 months is not a problem, it happens to I also have 4 months' experience in my profile. Guess what, no any problem!

2, In most of countries, background check only check the companies you input. They don't know the company not show in the CV, or the companies you didn't input.

3, But the point 2) is not always right, for example, in China, any background check companies are able to find your whole working records in Social departments, you don't even has to provide your CV!

Comment: Thanks for included example from other countries. Just lovely.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting positions is usually not a problem on a CV. The bigger problem is the inverse, i.e. listing jobs that you never had.

There are plenty of jobs I have worked in the past which I no longer mention on my CV simply because they are not relevant to the job I'm applying for.

> The job is not relevant to this new position

And since this is also the case for you, then it shouldn't be a problem. If they ask you why you didn't list the job, simply mentioned that you omitted it due to its irrelevance to the position you were applying for.

Answer (score 0):

> This 4 month gig was not listed on my resume nor the application.

It doesn't have to be on your resume. You only have to include the jobs that you feel can help you get the job be listing relevant experience, or in the case of jobs that don't relate directly to the new job they show experience that you want to show.

Not including it on the application can be an issue. Many times the application says to list all jobs going back x years. Or they say list your last y jobs. You are supposed to follow the directions.

In some cases the information on the application is what they use for the starting point of the background check. Other times the background check has a separate form.

> It will show up on the background check.

It MIGHT show up in the background check.

> Should I explain to the hiring manager now or wait for the background
> check. The job is not relevant to this new position nor is it listed
> on social media (LinkedIn or FB)

If they find the job you didn't list, the hiring manager might be concerned that you were trying to hide something. Telling them now might avoid that concern. Some  people don't list a short job is because they were fired, or they didn't get along with the manager and don't want the new company to contact them.

Contacting the hiring manger might be as quick as a short email, or a quick phone call. That's what I would do.